# Accessing HttpServletRequest request in child thread

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, servlets, requestcontext

I have a web application, in which i am using ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor to schedule some logic to be executed later (maybe after original web request is over). Is it possible to access/use HttpServletRequest of original request inside child thread (created via "schedule" call on ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor)?

I tried autowiring HttpServletRequest inside class whose function is running in child thread, but got following error (which i understand the reason for)

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are 
    you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request,
    or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If
    you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this
    message, your code is probably running outside of
    DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use
    RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current
    request.
```

Is there any possible way?
Can [RequestContextFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/RequestContextFilter.html#setThreadContextInheritable-boolean-) be possibly used?

Comment: No. The request object, and the request-scoped spring beans, are not supposed to be used after the request has been handled, or even in a separate thread. Extract the data you need for the scheduled job, then submit a task using this data to the executor.

Comment: can [BeanUtils] (http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.0/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.java) be used to copy HttpServletRequest object?

Comment: Why would you need an HttpServletRequest object in the scheduled job? Extract the data needed by the scheduled job to an object, and pass that object to the job.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you are trying to accomplish is to have the HTTP Connection kept open while the processing of the request is handled asynchronously in a separate thread?

In this case you might want to take a look at the DefferedResult support in Spring MVC - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/DeferredResult.html - also explained here - http://java.dzone.com/articles/long-polling-spring-32s